# I downgraded my npm version to 5.5.1, and now I can't set it back

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, npm-install

I ran this:

```
sudo npm i -g npm@5.5.1
```

And now I can't do anything to update npm back to the latest version. Even running:

```
sudo npm i -g npm@5.5.2
```

Gives an error:

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v16.17.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for npm@5.5.2
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Henry/.npm/_logs/2022-10-08T19_05_16_673Z-debug.log
```

This is some other stuff I've tried that also has not worked:

`nvm install-latest-npm`

`npm install latest-version`

Comment: I would suggest using `nvm`

Answer (score 1):

After trying ~15 different commands that all failed, this one worked!

`nvm install --latest-npm`

I have no idea why this particular command worked and everything else failed, but hey, I'll take it.

Comment: Everything that is called via `npm` or `npx` uses the installed node instance, which isn't compatible with the old version of `npm`. `nvm` on the other hand is a set of bash scripts which don't rely on `node` so those scripts can still work